# SitePicker PnP control not returning any value in my one of the tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, pnpjs

PropertyFieldSitePicker Pnp control not returning any value in my one of the tenant but in another tenant, it's working fine.

**Scenario**: I have created one SPFx solution with PropertyFieldSitePicker control

After deploying SPFx solution in tenant A then PropertyFieldSitePicker control returning the sites and after deploying same SPFX Solution in another tenant then PropertyFieldSitePicker showing no results

In Both the tenant I have sites

**Code** :

```
PropertyFieldSitePicker("selectsitefornewlist", {
label: "",
initialSites: this.properties.selectsitefornewlist,
context: this.context,
deferredValidationTime: 500,
onPropertyChange: this.onNewSitepickerchange,
properties: this.properties,
key: "sitesFieldId",
})
```

Search API coming in both the tenant network tab

*In Tenant A below Search Api Coming* :

```
https://tenantA.sharepoint.com/teams/test/_api/search/query?querytext=%27contentclass:STS_Site%20contentclass:STS_Web%20Title:*int*%20Path:https://tenantA.sharepoint.com*%27&selectproperties=%27SiteId,Title,Path%27&rowlimit=5
```

*In Tenant B below search, API coming*

```
https://tenantB.sharepoint.com/teams/test/_api/search/query?querytext=%27contentclass:STS_Site%20contentclass:STS_Web%20Title:*int*%20Path:https://tenantB.sharepoint.com*%27&selectproperties=%27SiteId,Title,Path%27&rowlimit=5
```

Noting returning from tenant B

if I modified the Title:*int* to Title: int* in search API from browser it's returning the value

- SPFx version: 1.11.0
- SPFx property Control version: ^2.2.0

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: No there is no error in console

Comment: @GaneshSanap No there is no error in the console.